# INSERT or UPDATE tables with SERIAL primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

Simple question,

How can I UPSERT in PostgreSQL tables, that have SERIAL (also knowns as auto increment) primary keys?

I couldn't find really believable source this is why I ask here.

This is what I got so far but It doesn't work.

```
INSERT INTO public.friendship (Username_1, Username_2, Status) 
VALUES ("User1", "User2", "Accepted") 
ON CONFLICT (Username_1, Username_2) 
DO UPDATE SET (Status) = ("Accepted")   
WHERE Username_1 = "User1" AND Username_2 = "User2";
```

Full schema (ER diagram). Table is "Friendship" but UMLStar exports weird SQL with "public.Friendship" like table names. But that doesn't matter, it works with other cases (I got Register/Login working successfully).

[image: Full schema]
Command \d, List of relations

```
 Schema |              Name               |   Type   |  Owner
--------+---------------------------------+----------+----------
 public | activitydata                    | table    | postgres
 public | activitydata_activitydataid_seq | sequence | postgres
 public | chatroom                        | table    | postgres
 public | chatroom_chatroomid_seq         | sequence | postgres
 public | country                         | table    | postgres
 public | friendship                      | table    | postgres
 public | friendship_friendshipid_seq     | sequence | postgres
 public | message                         | table    | postgres
 public | message_messageid_seq           | sequence | postgres
 public | participates                    | table    | postgres
 public | participates_participatesid_seq | sequence | postgres
 public | user                            | table    | postgres
(12 rows)
```

messenger=# \d Friendship

```
Table "public.friendship"
    Column    |  Type   |                             Modifiers
--------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 friendshipid | integer | not null default nextval('friendship_friendshipid_seq'::regclass)
 username_1   | text    | not null
 username_2   | text    | not null
 status       | text    | not null
Indexes:
    "friendship_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (friendshipid)
    "friendship_username_1_idx" btree (username_1)
    "friendship_username_2_idx" btree (username_2)
```

Executed command:

```
messenger=# INSERT INTO public.friendship (Username_1, Username_2, Status)
messenger-# VALUES ('User1', 'User2', 'Accepted')
messenger-#  ON CONFLICT (Username_1, Username_2)
messenger-#  DO UPDATE SET (Status) = ('Accepted')
messenger-#  WHERE Username_1 = 'User1' AND Username_2 = 'User2';
ERROR:  column reference "username_1" is ambiguous
LINE 5:  WHERE Username_1 = 'User1' AND Username_2 = 'User2';
```

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean?

Comment: Do you have a UNIQUE key on (Username_1, Username_2)? Paste the results of `\d Friendship`

Comment: Why should I have UNIQUE on Username_1 and Username_2?

User table has Username which is PK (UNIQUE)

Comment: Because presumably the PK is a surrogate key and you'll never conflict if you're only unique on the surrogate key, unless the surrogate key is in the INSERT/UPDATE source too.

Comment: How do you expect to conflict on Username_1 or Username_2 if they're not unique?

Comment: Username_1 + Username_2 pair is UNIQUE, well should be. 

Does FriendshipID even makes sense? No other tables reference to it.

By the way, updating psql right now, I am in middle of conflict, I think I will need to reinstall it all. Will run \d ASAP.

Comment: Cool, so long as you have a non-defferable unique constraint on (update_1, update_2) your statement should work on conflict. So we need to know more to know why it's not working. We await the `\d`

Comment: Here, \d ran. I have updated PSQL from 9.49 to 9.6 btw, it should help I think. Also Evan thanks for helping me!

Comment: Nooo, \d Friendship. And then the error messages from the command that didn't work.

Comment: Here, updated. Also, I replaced character( " ) with character( ' ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133492/discussion-between-vili-volcini-and-evan-carroll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table "public.friendship"
    Column    |  Type   |                             Modifiers
--------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 friendshipid | integer | not null default nextval('friendship_friendshipid_seq'::regclass)
 username_1   | text    | not null
 username_2   | text    | not null
 status       | text    | not null
Indexes:
    "friendship_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (friendshipid)
    "friendship_username_1_idx" btree (username_1)
    "friendship_username_2_idx" btree (username_2)
```

This doesn't show a unique key on `(username_1, username_2)`

What you should do is

```
BEGIN;
  DROP INDEX friendship_username_1_idx,
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON foo(username_1, username_2);
COMMIT;
```

If you never query on `username_2` without also querying on `username_1` then you should drop `friendship_username_2_idx` and let the one compound UNIQUE index work for you.

For reference we wanted `\d Friendship` because if you had a unique index it would show...

```
      Table "public.foo"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 a      | integer | 
 b      | integer | 
Indexes:
    "foo_a_b_idx" UNIQUE, btree (a, b)
```

Without something there, how can you get a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if I have missed the complexity of the question but this seems simpler:

```
ALTER TABLE public.friendship 
add column id serial;
```